# i want to store readed file output in variable

Tags: php, file, fileoutputstream

in PHP I want each string read by "fgets()" function in a separate variable.
Below is my code

```
$handle = @fopen("txtfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

An output of this code is:

```
I am Demo
```

I want this output as:

```
$word1 = I
$word2 = am
$word3 = Demo
```

Comment: You want the output to actually be the string of the variable name as well? Or no actual "output" but the result is each of the 4096 byte blocks in a sequentially named variable? Or... do you want it split by word?

Comment: yes, I want to split and store each word in a separate variable. @kchason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$handle = @fopen("txtfile.txt", "r");
$text = '';
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $text .= $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$array = explode(' ', $text);

$i = 1;

foreach ($array as $word) {
    ${"word$i"} = $word;
    $i++;
}
```

Now you have each word saved in a different var

Comment: thanks. This works for me. I need the same result but without using explode function @sanNeck